# React-Native openURL Twitter Link Issues

Tags: react-native

I'm displaying a twitter feed in my app which is being pulled in from the twitter API. As the tweets don't show the full text there is a twitter short code URL (t.co) to view the full tweet.

The problem I'm having is when I click the URL using openURL it opens in a browser, which redirects to the twitter app and redirects back to the browser to display the tweet.

This works if I have the twitter app already open - if it's not open the final redirect back to the browser doesn't load the page.

Everything works fine if there's no twitter app installed it just loads in a browser.

Is there a way to avoid the redirects and just have the t.co URLs open in the twitter app if it's installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this issue by first creating a URL unshortener in PHP:

```
<?php 
$url = $_GET['url'];

$context = stream_context_create(
array(
    'http' => array(
        'follow_location' => false
    )
)
);

$html = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$final = str_replace("location: ",'',$http_response_header[5]);

echo json_encode ($final,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

Then from react-native fetch the full URL from the unshortener:

```
if (href.contains('https')) {

    var short = {
        getInfo() {

          var myUrl = 'expander.php?url='+href

            return fetch(myUrl).then((res) => res.json()).catch(function(error) {
                Alert.alert(error+''); 
            });
        }
    }

   short.getInfo().then((res) => {

    var final = res.replace('i/web','web');

    Linking.openURL(final);   

   })
} else {

  Linking.openURL(href)
}
```

It was important to replace 'i/web' in the URL string with 'web' so the app opens the link natively rather than opening a mobile link.